# There is no way to verify whether the user's iPhone is enabled in developer mode in my iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, developer-mode

For security reasons, my program needed to verify that the iPhone was in developer mode. In the current iOS version (16.0), there is a problem in development, and there is no way to verify whether the user's iPhone is enabled in developer mode in the project.

I didn't find the documentation to implement this requirement.

Comment: There is no api to detect developer mode

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, Thank you very much. I tried to find it for a long, long time.